# Possible timing error with Google Charts JSON call

Tags: php, json, google-visualization

I've spent the best part of a day attempting a pie chart, and now I have a pie chart, it tells me lies! It says there is one series, accounting for 100% which is incorrect! Could someone please tell me where I am going wrong.

So far, I have this:

```
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js">       
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi">      
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">

google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});

function drawChart() {

  var jsonData = $.ajax({
  url: "getdata_searches.php",
  dataType:"json",
  async: false
  }).responseText;

// Create our data table out of JSON data loaded from server.
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonData);

var options = {
  title: 'Searches By Type'
};

var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart'));

chart.draw(data, options);
}

google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
</script>
```

My getdata_searches.php file is so:

```
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql="Select Other, Count(Other) As Count From activity WHERE tel = '0000' AND Other <> '' Group By Other Order By Count(Other) Desc;";

$result = $conn->query($sql);

$data = array('cols' => array(array('label' => 'Other', 'type' => 'string'),
                        array('label' => 'Count', 'type' => 'number')),
              'rows' => array());

while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $data['rows'][] = array('c' => array(array('v' => $row["Other"]), array('v' => $row["Count"])));
}

echo json_encode($data);
```

which produces:

```
{
"cols":[
    {"label":"Other","type":"string"},
    {"label":"Count","type":"number"}],
"rows":[
    {"c":[{"v":"AVS Search"},{"v":"215"}]},
    {"c":[{"v":"Urgent Care Centres"},{"v":"50"}]},
    {"c":[{"v":"Emer. Depts"},{"v":"37"}]},
    {"c":[{"v":"Adult Trauma Networks"},{"v":"19"}]}
    ]
}
```

I've gone round and round in circles on this one, I must be missing something obvious, please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem appears to be the values for the "Count" column.

`String "215"` instead of `Number 215`.

Created the code snippet using corrected `JSON` you provided...

```js
google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});

function drawChart() {

    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable({
        "cols":[
            {"label":"Other","type":"string"},
            {"label":"Count","type":"number"}
        ],
        "rows":[
            {"c":[{"v":"AVS Search"},{"v":215}]},
            {"c":[{"v":"Urgent Care Centres"},{"v":50}]},
            {"c":[{"v":"Emer. Depts"},{"v":37}]},
            {"c":[{"v":"Adult Trauma Networks"},{"v":19}]}
        ]
    });

    var options = {
        title: 'Searches By Type'
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart'));

    chart.draw(data, options);
}

google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
```

```html
<script src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>

<div id="piechart"></div>
```

Comment: Perfect! Altered       `$data['rows'][] = array('c' => array(array('v' => $row["Other"]), array('v' => $row["Count"])));` to `$data['rows'][] = array('c' => array(array('v' => $row["Other"]), array('v' => (int) $row["Count"])));` thanks very much